# d3.js example of a dynamic image gallery

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking to create a image gallery where the images layout nicely on a page according to a ranking score. So the images with a higher score get more screen space (bigger width and height)

I'm new to d3.js, and looking for a good starting point. Does anyone have a good example or suggestion?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found that setting an image into a treemap is a great way to do what I wanted: https://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/79409cca5bcc57c32ddae0a5f0a1a564

This worked great for my use case.